# How to run a function within a loop grouped by a factor?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, data.table, lapply

I am trying to loop the function `f` across data frame `df` and store the output in result. The function samples values from `v` and stored in v.sample. However, I want the function to ONLY loop and hence sample v while keeping m within the same species `sp`

```
set.seed(100)
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,11,11,11,11,11,500,782,234,124,566)
v <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,11,11,11,11,11,60,80,123,44,55)
sp <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=5)

df <- data.frame(x, v, sp)
df$sp <- as.factor(df$sp)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)

f <- function(x, v) {
  v.sample <- sample(v, length(v), replace=TRUE)
  y.sample <- (v.sample/x^2) - (1/x)
  per <- cor(y.sample, x, use="complete.obs")
  # storing all vectors in a dataframe
  data.frame( v.sample = v.sample, y.sample = y.sample, rand.cor = per)
}

result <- rbindlist(
  lapply(1:9, \(i)  df[, .(f(x, v),x,v, sp)][, i:=i])
)
```

Currently, the v.sample is shuffling across all the species. For instance, in the way I have setup the dummy dataset, the v.sample for `sp == A` must only be 1; whereas `sp == D` must vary between `44 and 123`. Currently, it is shuffling across all species `sp`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the data, then run your UDF on each `sp`, and wrap the results by `rbindlist`. Maybe there's an approach using group `by` but I couldn't figure it out.

```
rbindlist(
          lapply(split(df, df$sp), function(dat)
              rbindlist(
                        lapply(1:9, function(i) 
dat[, .(f(x, v), x, v, sp)][, i:=i])
                        )
          )
)
```

```
#>      v.sample      y.sample  rand.cor   X   V SP i
#>   1:        1  0.000000e+00        NA   1   1  A 1
#>   2:        1  0.000000e+00        NA   1   1  A 1
#>   3:        1  0.000000e+00        NA   1   1  A 1
#>   4:        1  0.000000e+00        NA   1   1  A 1
#>   5:        1  0.000000e+00        NA   1   1  A 1
#>  ---                                              
#> 176:       44 -1.824000e-03 -0.311902 500  60  D 9
#> 177:       80 -1.147952e-03 -0.311902 782  80  D 9
#> 178:      123 -2.027175e-03 -0.311902 234 123  D 9
#> 179:      123 -6.503642e-05 -0.311902 124  44  D 9
#> 180:       55 -1.595100e-03 -0.311902 566  55  D 9
```

Comment: I have a clarification: What is `dat` in `function(dat)` ? What is it doing?

Comment: Awww...good chance to use `by`, very equivalent to `lapply` + `split`: `...by(df, df$sp, function(dat)...`

Comment: @Biotechgeek using split I make a list of dataframes for each sp. Then I loop over each of those.

Answer (score 1):

If a solution using **dplyr** interests you at all, this does what you outline I think:

```
library(dplyr)
f <- function(.data, ...){
  .data %>%
    mutate(v_sample = sample(x = v,size = n(),replace = TRUE),
           y_sample = (v_sample / x^2) - (1/x),
           rand_cor = cor(y_sample,x,use = 'complete.obs'))
}

rep_f <- function(.data, n = 9, ...){
  replicate(n = n,expr = f(.data), simplify = FALSE)
}

df %>%
  group_by(sp) %>%
  group_map(.f = ~rep_f(.x,n = 9)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Note that the way you've set up the data, `cor()` throws lots of warnings due to constant data so you get a sd of zero.

Comment: Nice +1. I couldn't figure out how to use something like ```lapply(1:9, function(i) dat[, .(f(X, V), X, V, SP), .(SP)][, i:=i])``` in `data.table` though. You probably need to include a loop since this is just one shuffle.

Comment: @M-- I'm not really sure I've read the question properly, tbh. It seems like maybe they want multiple shufflings for each value of the factor, rather than just once by group.

Comment: @joran This looks like a promising solution. But there is no function to work with. How do I do the last bit of doing the shuffling without a function?

Comment: @Biotechgeek I don't think I was doing what you asked initially, but I believe this does, replicating each shuffling multiple times per group.

Answer (score 1):

Since `f` returns a list, we must combine the results of `f` with `x` and `v` using `c()` in order to use a `data.table` grouping operation on `sp`.

```
result <- rbindlist(
  lapply(1:9, \(i)  df[, c(f(x, v), .(x, v)), sp]),
  idcol = "i"
)
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I was trying to do. +1